# Display font awesome icons before text

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I want to add a like icon/button before the word "Like" , I tried font awesome but the "i" tag will only display the text "Like" in Italic. Although the snippet works here, but it wouldn't work when I write it on my editor, I tried it with both IE and Chrome, still not working

this is the link I used for CDN:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
```

and this is the HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4"><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary"><i class="fa  fa-thumbs-up">Like</i></button></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><button class="btn btn-block btn-info">Info</button></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><button class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Delete</button></div>

</div>
```

demo:

```css
h2 {
  font-family: Lobster, Monospace;
}

.thick-green-border {
  border-color: green;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fluid-container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h2 class="red-text text-center">CatPhotoApp</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <a href="https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl"><img class="img-responsive thick-green-border" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg"></a>
    </div>

  </div>



  <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/running-cats.jpg" class="img-responsive">


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4"><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up">Like</i></button></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><button class="btn btn-block btn-info">Info</button></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><button class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Delete</button></div>

  </div>


  <p>Things cats <span class="text-danger">love</span>:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>cat nip</li>
    <li>laser pointers</li>
    <li>lasagna</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Top 3 things cats hate:</p>
  <ol>
    <li>flea treatment</li>
    <li>thunder</li>
    <li>other cats</li>
  </ol>
  <form action="/submit-cat-photo">
    <label><input type="radio" name="indoor-outdoor"> Indoor</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="indoor-outdoor"> Outdoor</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="personality"> Loving</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="personality"> Lazy</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="personality"> Crazy</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="cat photo URL" required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Please, show us a live Demo

Comment: Your code is working.

Comment: @NiZa I've included a snippet and it works her, but somehow when I code it in sublime text and open it in chrome, the text will turn italic, but no icons will be added

Comment: @pedram I've included a snippet

Comment: You want to show `font awesome` icon in `italic` ?

Comment: @pedram nope, sorry was a typo , I want to show a like button inline before the word text

Comment: if I understand you right, you want [This](https://jsfiddle.net/g6deom8u/) right? or not?

Comment: Please state your question, or what you want to do somewhere in the question. Right now it's just a dump of code.

Comment: it worked already, just needed to write the full link of CDN, thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open this page not like `file:///...` which I assume you do locally.

Your CDN does not specify protocol: `href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"` so it takes it from the page container. And if you open page as `file:///` it'll try to look for `file:///maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css` which does not exist.

If you still want to make it work from file, please, change:

> href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"

to

> href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"

Comment: first time OP want to show icon in italic, then want to show icon before text, funny.. So looks like the problem is OP got a issue in local..  it was not clear what OP want, it made me confused.. sorry.

Comment: This is a common error for new developers, who are working with CDN locally. Students do it a lot.